# Is read or cat more efficient when reading a file into a string?

Tags: shell, fork, built-in

I had someone on Stack Overflow with a very high reputation suggest that using read (the builtin) was very slow. I know you have to use an external and a subshell to use cat in this manner, but which of these is more efficient when reading in a large text file? This one:

```
#!/bin/sh

string="$(cat file)"
```

Or this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

newline='
'

string=
while IFS= read -r line; do
    string="${string}${line}${newline}"
done < file
if [ -n "$line" ]; then
    string="${string}${line}"
fi
```

Comment: You can do the following experiment:  
Just prepare some big input files `100MB`, `1GB`, `10GB`, ... and measure the execution time of both version using: `time <+your cmd>` or the difference between 2 dates (before and after the execution). Repeat this experiment a couple of times and compare both versions! To be checked but I think that the `cat` version will be faster for big input files, because you have many concatenation operations at each step in your reading loop!!!

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the person's advice. If you implement `cat` as a `while read f; do echo "$f"; done` style loop, it's true that it will indeed be much slower. However, the takeaway is "use pipelines when possible", and not "replace all uses of `read` with `cat`" because that's way worse. In this case, you're reading lots of data into a shell variable which is already a bad approach. You're asking about the fastest way to do the slowest thing.

Comment: `string="$(cat file)"` is an *Unnecessary Use Of `cat`* (a UUOc). The proper form is `string="$(<file)"`. Use redirection when redirecting a file and `cat` when *concatenating* more than 1 file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not if you're trying to write portable scripts. `string="$(<file)"` is a bashism

Comment: If you have to ask this question, you are using the wrong language, really, IMHO.

Comment: @HaroldFischer - you are correct. I had a bash tag stuck in my mind for some reason.